# Как посчитать сколько раз символ встречается в строке?

Tags: python, строки, символы, генераторы

Дана строка s = 'good shene', надо создать словарь, где для всех символов, встречающихся в строке, хранится число: сколько раз символ встретился в строке. Для решения задачи надо использовать генератор.

Comment: `'abcabcabd'.count('c')` или `'abcabcabd'.count('abc')`. А вообще такие вещи гуглом за 10 секунд находятся... ;)

Comment: @MaxU в ответ его! :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, добавил на тот случай если кто-то из гугла сюда прийдет...

Comment: @MaxU строка уже задана, например   для строки s = 'good shene' создать словарь, где для всех символов, встречающихся в строке, хранится число: сколько раз символ встретился в строке. нужно использовать генераторы, чтобы решить задачу в одну строку.

Comment: @gogglelesha, нажмите [кнопку "править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/735924/edit) и исправьте вопрос...

Comment: @gogglelesha, я правильно понимаю что [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) использовать нельзя? Т.е. использование генератора - это обязательное условие?

Comment: @MaxU да, это обязательное условие

Comment: Данную задачу можно и без генератора в одну строку решить

Answer (score 5):

Ответ на вопрос **после** правки:

```
In [17]: s
Out[17]: 'good shene'

In [18]: {c:s.count(c) for c in set(s)}
Out[18]: {' ': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 2, 'g': 1, 'h': 1, 'n': 1, 'o': 2, 's': 1}
```

Классический вариант решения (если нет обязательного условия использовать генераторы):

```
In [23]: from collections import Counter

In [24]: c = Counter(s)

In [25]: c
Out[25]: Counter({' ': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 2, 'g': 1, 'h': 1, 'n': 1, 'o': 2, 's': 1})

In [26]: c.most_common(1)
Out[26]: [('o', 2)]
```

---

Ответ на вопрос **до** правки:

Примеры:

```
In [3]: 'abcabcabd'.count('c')
Out[3]: 2

In [4]: 'abcabcabd'.count('abc')
Out[4]: 2

In [5]: 'abcabcabd'.count('abd')
Out[5]: 1
```

тоже самое можно проделать с переменными:

```
In [6]: s1 = 'aaabbbcccdxyz'

In [7]: s2 = 'a'

In [8]: s1.count(s2)
Out[8]: 3

In [9]: s1.count('xyz')
Out[9]: 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Ответ на вопрос до правки

```
import re
mystr = 'abcdeabcdabcdefg'
p = re.compile('d')
len(p.findall(mystr))
```

Ответ на вопрос после правки

```
my_dict = {}
s = 'good shene' 
for k in s:
    if my_dict.has_key(k): my_dict[k] += 1
    else: my_dict[k] = 1
print my_dict
{' ': 1, 'e': 2, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, 'h': 1, 'o': 2, 'n': 1, 's': 1}
```